# Applying automatic and hidden filtering to a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, lambda, generic-list

OK.

I have a class MyClass and another class that is based on List. Let's call it MyCollection.

Now when someone types:

```
MyCollection coll = new MyCollection();
...
coll.Find(...)
```

They are acting on the *entire* collection. I want to apply some filtering - behind the scenes - so that if they write the above code, what *actually* executes is something like...

```
coll.Where(x=>x.CanSeeThis).Find(...)
```

What do I need to write in the definition of the MyCollection class to make this work?

Can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to write a wrapper class that implements `IList` or `ICollection`, using a regular `List` internally. This wrapper class would then proxy all method calls to the internal list, applying the filter as required.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to find a way of shoe-horning this filter in without having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You´ve already mentioned you´ve got your own collection, probably derived from List right?
Then you´ll need to create your own method for finding:

```
public class MyList<T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
{
  public IEnumerable<T> MyFind(Predicate<T> match)
  {
    return this.Where(x => x.CanSeeThis).ToList().Find(match);
  }
}
```

This unfortunatly is needed because you cannot override the Find method on List directly. You can however use the 'new' keyword to specify that If you´ve got a reference to the instance of MyList it will use that implementation of find, like below:

```
  public new IEnumerable<T> Find(Predicate<T> match)
  {
    return this.Where(x => x.CanSeeThis).ToList().Find(match);
  }
```

However the above example will yield:

```
MyCollection<int> collection = new ...
collection.Find(myPredicate); // <= Will use YOUR Find-method

List<int> baseTypeCollection = collection; // The above instantiated
baseTypeCollection.Find(myPredicate); // Will use List<T>.Find!
```

So it´s better you make you´re own method.

Comment: Hmm. OK. But if I wanted to write things so that /any/ access to the list was via my filter, I'd have to reproduce/replace /all/ of those methods of the base class, yes?

Comment: I guess, thinking about it more, what I really want, is the default access method of my collection to be the filtered version so that users of it can use .AnyThing(...) and have it operate on the filtered collection rather than the raw data.

Comment: Yep thats right. Best you could do is to implement the IList interface I guess and then use an internal list that´ll contain your data and then you´d just filter any parameters to the List's methods using your filtering condition. It´s a pain in the ass that the List isn't more overrideable, been there myself :)

Comment: It's not THAT painful - you do this once, in a generic way, and you'll have yourself the extensible collection type that should have been there in the first place.

Comment: Yea. You´re completely right.. I´ll not take more than a coffe break really but.. there´s no programmer that can't admit to beeing a little bit lazy :)

Comment: I don't even /know/ Almund, but he appears to know me!

Comment: I'll have a bash at knocking up the class using IList and an internal List<T>. Thanks guys.